# Traveling to USA with Taiwanese wife for two week vacation

Tags: visas, us-visa-waiver-program

I would like to know if the Visa Waiver Program is all she needs to travel to USA. We have been married for 7 years and live in Taiwan. I am a citizen of USA. She has filled out the ESTA( part of (VWP) online. We both have jobs in Taiwan and own a house. We just want to visit. She has the new passport with the chip.

Answer (score 4):

[As of November 1 2012 citizens of Taiwan may travel to the US under the Visa Waiver program](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1550/session/L2F2LzEvdGltZS8xNDIyNDcwMzk0L3NpZC93NHlfSkJkbQ%3D%3D/~/visa-waiver-program---eligible-countries).

There are no additional requirements for Taiwanese citizens over and above other visa waiver countries.